# Create MDI child forms Singltone mode

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

Using the Singleton class, provide the ability to create the number of MDI forms not exceeding the specified number (for example, 3).

I created class, but i dont know how to limit number of forms there:

```
 public class GenericSingleton<T> where T : Form, new()
    {
        private static T t = null;
        public static T CreateInstrance()
        {
            if (null == t || t.IsDisposed)
            {
                t = new T();
            }
            return t;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what problem do you encounter, what have you tried?

Comment: Edit your question to provide more details, not the commentsection.

Comment: You can modify this procedure: [Simplify the creation of MDI child Forms based on their Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66053267/7444103) to check whether `Count()` (instead of `Any()`) is `>=` a specific value.