# Proper instatiating a WinForm via string in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Winforms application that uses base window (e.g. Form1) and many other windows (e.g. Form2, Form3, ...). All of these windows have their property TopLevel set to false, no border and I am placing them in the Form1 when I need them. I am not skilled enough or do not have the brain capacity to solve this issue:

```
public void ShowForm(string strNewForm) {
   var frmNew = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(strNewForm)) as Form;

   frmNew.TopLevel = false;
   frmNew.Size = new Size(rctForm.Width, rctForm.Height);
   frmNew.Location = new Point(rctForm.X, rctForm.Y);
   frmNew.InitializeForm(strActualSection, strActualSubSection);
   frmNew.Parent = this;

   frmNew.Show();  
}
```

The `strNewForm` variable contains the name of `Form` to show. All the methods and properties in each Form can be used as these all are inherited from base class `Form`. Problem is with `InitializeForm()` which I use in each form (Form2, Form3, ...) to do various stuff. I know my problem is in this line:

```
var frmNew = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(strNewForm)) as Form;
```

When `strNewForm` contains string "Form2" and I change `as Form` to `as Form2` it works just fine. I know I need to change it to proper name each time, but I don't know how. I tried to use this:

```
Type frmType = Type.GetType(strNewForm);
var frmNew = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(strNewForm)) as frmType;
```

But it throws an error `CS0118: frmType is a variable but is used as a type`. I don't know how to solve this, I tried many solutions and I googled for half a day straight and I am still lost. Any insight would be really helpful.

Comment: [Simplify the creation of MDI child Forms based on their Type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66053267/7444103) -- Applies to non-MDI Forms as well, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a run-time variable to create strongly-typed code.

You have to provide a compile-time type after the `as`.

If you know it's a `Form` then all you can do is this:

```
var frmNew = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(strNewForm)) as Form;
```

If you need specific methods or properties then use a custom `Form` as your base-type and use that in the `as`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I had to choose different approach. I tried to avoid a long list of switch-case, but I didn't evade it in the end.

Comment: @Bajt - There are very few times that you need to use a switch statement. It would have been great if you showed more of the bigger picture of what you're doing. We could have given you a much better answer.

Answer (score -1):

Why won't you pass a `Form` object in your `ShowForm` method?

```cs
public void ShowForm(Form newForm) 
{
   newForm.TopLevel = false;
   newForm.Size = new Size(rctForm.Width, rctForm.Height);
   newForm.Location = new Point(rctForm.X, rctForm.Y);
   newForm.InitializeForm(strActualSection, strActualSubSection);
   newForm.Parent = this;

   newForm.ShowDialog();  
}
```

Comment: How does this solve `frmType is a variable but is used as a type`?

Comment: I was just proposing an alternative way...instead of passing the form's name to the method and try to parse to a `Form` object, it'd be much easier to pass a form instead to the method and forget the idea of parsing to a `Form` object altogether.

Comment: The OP is clearly trying to dynamically create forms. You're proposing he drops that and statically creates them?

Comment: The key issue here for the OP is how to create the form. You're skipping that entirely.

Comment: @Enigmativity I get your point now. Let's see his reaction to your proposition....which I still agree with. Mine clearly suggests a different work-flow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).